Ensuring Single and Double Column Figures Appear on the Same Page
I need to position a single-column figure at the top and a double-column figure at the bottom of the same page. However, with the following MWE, the figures are not appearing on the same page as intended. I also tried with dblfloatfix with no solution.
MWE:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-5}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
\caption{1}
\end{figure}

%WHEN THIS LINE PRESENT THEN WE ARE GETTING THE DESIRED OUTPUT%Some Text content for testing phase only. Some Text content for testing phase only. 

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
\caption{2} 
\end{figure*}

\lipsum{1}

\end{document}


First of all note, that \lipsum has an optional argument but not a mandatory. So, e.g., your \lipsum{1-5} is the same like \lipsum\begingroup 1-5\endgroup. Note also, that \lipsum without optional argument initially is the same like \lipsum[1-7]. I've taken this into account in my example below.
There are several limitations for bottom placed column spanning floats (and each package that supports it, has some other limitations). Because of those limitations it often helps to move the column spanning float a little bit. In your case moving it a little bit backwards does indeed help:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[!t]
\vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
\caption{1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]% move one lipsum paragraph *before* the bottom figure

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
\caption{2} 
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2-7]

\end{document}


In the shown example using nidanfloat instead of stfloats would also help:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nidanfloat}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-5}% See my note about the (incorrect) argument.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
\caption{1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
\vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
\caption{2} 
\end{figure*}

\lipsum{1}% See my note about the (incorrect) argument.

\end{document}


In your real document you also should try to move the figure* inside the source. However note, that the main reason to use a float is to allow LaTeX to find a suitable position. It is not intended to restrict material to a fix position. For static positions there are other mechanisms like shipout hooks, e.g., in combination with \enlargethispage, or maybe something like flowfram. But without knowing much more about your document and why you want exactly this placement, I cannot tell you, what else you could use and which would be the IMHO best solution.

I'm new at this, but I got the same result by moving the two figures right next to each other, one after the other.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-5}

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
    \caption{1}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
\begin{figure*}[!b]
    \vbox{\fbox{\vbox to 10pc{\hbox to 5pc{}}}}
    \caption{2} 
\end{figure*}

\lipsum{1}

\end{document}


In the original post the first image is at the top of the second page. In your example both images are at the first page. I don't know, if this matters.

You are right. Bad solution on my part. If I add the \lipsum command back in after the second figure, the second box moves to the next page as before.

Because of this, I've told in my answer to move only some of the text but not all. ;-)

I ran across the command \pagebreak and edited the code above. That seems to work? By the way, if this works, I have to thank Google's AI for the suggestion and latexref.xyz for the details.
